# Error 400 (Bad request) during POST request

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, post

I'm trying to send a *POST* request to my server from my *react* application but however i keep getting a **status 400 Bad Request** error. *The exception is*:

**"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException".**

*The error message is*:

**"JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6a188b06; line: 1, column: 1]"**

I tried testing the API with *POSTMAN* but i still keep getting the same error.

```
@PostMapping("/cart")
public Cart create(@RequestBody CartRequest cartRequest){
  return cartRepository.save(new Cart(0,cartRequest.getProductname()));
}
```

My models class is

```
public class CartRequest {
String productname;

public CartRequest(int productid, String productname) {
    this.productname = productname;
}


public String getProductname() {
    return productname;
}

public void setProductname(String productname) {
    this.productname = productname;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CartRequest{" +
            ", productname='" + productname + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

The repository class is follows

```
public interface CartRespository extends JpaRepository<Cart, Integer> {
    }
```

The request code is as follows

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import NavBar from "./navbar";
export default class Products extends Component {
state = {
    isLoading: true,
    groups: [],
};

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    {
         this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    }
}
add(id, name) {
    axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api/cart',
    body: {
      productid: id,
      productname: name
    }
  });
}

async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('api/product');
    const body = await response.json();
    this.setState({ groups: body, isLoading: false });
}
```

The Button that sends the requests is as follows

```
{this.state.groups.map(group => <button key={group.id} onClick={() => this.add(group.productid, group.name)} className="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">Add to Cart</button>)}
```

What I'm tryinig to perform is to recieve the information from a product and add it to a shopping cart.

The information of the product has been received using a *GET* request.

Comment: either add some react code or remove react from the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your controller's method looks like this:

```java
@PostMapping("/cart")
public Cart create(@RequestBody Map<Integer, Integer> body){
    int productid = body.get("productid");
    String productname=body.get("productname");

    return cartRepository.save(new Cart(productid, productname));
}
```

By the way, you can receive your json as a model, not a Map. You'd better create a new model class - CartRequest with one field for now - `productname`, and accept taht model in the controller

```java
@PostMapping("/cart")
public Cart create(@RequestBody CartRequest cartRequest){ 
  return cartRepository.save(new Cart(0, cartRequest.getProductname()));
}
```

As you can see, I didn't say to include `productid` field in the model. This is because your entity has to have no id when it gets saved by ORM (e.g. hibernate)

Comment: Tried it creating the new model class, still getting the same error :(

Comment: Could you please share your js code that makes the request? There is probably some issue with the request

Comment: Try to replace ```body``` with ```data``` in axios parameters

Comment: same error. The thing is it sends the same error on Postman as well. So I doubt it has something to do with the react code

Comment: [
    {
        "productid": 1,
        "productname":"example"
    }
]

Comment: Try to send this one: { "productid": 1, "productname":"example" }

Comment: Your controller's method can only receive a single Cart, not an array of them. If you want to receive an array, you have to use List<CartRequest> in the method

Comment: yes I know but Im sending only a single cart at the time being. Doesn't seem to work

Comment: When you are using square brackets in the request, it's treated as an array, even if it contains only one item. If you're still getting this error even with the json I've provided, could you please update the question with up-to-date controller.

Comment: The error is still the same. I've updated the question

Comment: I can't reproduce the error  with this json - { "productid": 1, "productname":"example"}, but if I wrap it with square brackets it fails with the same error

Comment: This is the error I get." Can not construct instance of me.salisuwy.Models.CartRequest: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of me.salisuwy.Models.CartRequest: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@9ca38d7;]"

Comment: Generate a default constrictor in the CartRequest class (constructor without parameters).

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thanks a lot Andrey Antipov for your efforts. :)

Comment: Great! As I can see from your update, you want to update a Cart, not to create a new one. In the answer I suggested to use a 0 as an I'd of Cart, and not to receive productid in CartRequest. But if you want to update the model, add productid to CartRequest, and pass cartRequest.getProductid() as a first parameters of Cart's constructor. Happy codding)